# How to integrate woocommerce rest api in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, woocommerce-rest-api

I want to integrate `WooCommerce rest API` in `angular js`.
Means I want to get the list of all product using `angular js` by use of `WooCommerce rest API`.

I'm using as this but it's not working :

http://angular.templatic.net/wp-json/wc/v1/products?oauth_consumer_key=ck_9ae878f7a1fa134a2acad1eef7c0182dd3f7e68a&oauth_nonce=0.07115150265051876&oauth_signature=cs_72e4b3ca15c1b9e326af8d806e47a1f95e76243c&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1455528864

Comment: I got the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41289977/use-woocommerce-rest-api-v1-with-http-and-javascript-not-https Did u find a solution?

Comment: @Steffan yes i found solutions and for me its working now....please try this way as mention here : https://github.com/jay2413/WC-API-JS-Client

Comment: Sorry, but its 67K lines of code in one file there. You dont have a 'smaller/shorter' version ?

Comment: No man...actually its available for node js version and from that its converted for angular js.

Comment: Thx, but I did find another solution, see first link..