# Use woocommerce rest api v1 with http and javascript (not https)

Tags: http, angular, oauth, woocommerce-rest-api, oauth-1.0a

Im using [oauth-signature](https://github.com/bettiolo/oauth-signature-js/blob/master/src/app/oauth-signature.js) to generate my oauth-signature for connection with woocommerce api. I followed all the steps stated at [woocommerce rest api documentation](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#authentication-over-http):

> The required parameters are: **oauth_consumer_key, oauth_timestamp, oauth_nonce, oauth_signature, and oauth_signature_method**. oauth_version is not required and should be omitted.
>   The OAuth nonce can be any randomly generated 32 character (recommended) string that is unique to the consumer key. etc...

But the following request still returns unauthorized:

http://siglar.no/wp-json/wc/v1/orders?oauth_consumer_key=ck_1ca1c6ff1a93de4836ee52c766538043d7f15d07&oauth_timestamp=1482431903&oauth_nonce=P5SM1FGeFVpdRyHWp4HHYOMlYAhxE6Gl&oauth_signature=cEETZUnSNQD6uorII9c%2B5SXf0M8%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1

*(Dont worry, the keys are only for local use)*

Response:

```
{"code":"woocommerce_rest_cannot_view","message":"Beklager, du kan ikke liste ressurser.","data":{"status":401}}
```

Im using WP 4.7, WC 2.6.9, API Activated for WC, SSL Deactivated for WC etc..

I also checked that this is done as required by the library:

> Generate the signature using the signature base string and your consumer secret key with a & character with the HMAC-SHA1 hashing algorithm.

The timezone is UNIX, and the nonce should be generated as required. So does some of you spot the problem? Here is my code:

```
constructor(private http: Http) {

    var d = new Date();
    var httpMethod = 'GET',
        url = 'http://siglar.no/wp-json/wc/v1/orders',
        ck = 'ck_1ca1c6ff1a93de4836ee52c766538043d7f15d07',
        cs = 'cs_ce323425064c37688d614e4ff43a5489c6f78017',
        sm = 'HMAC-SHA1',
        nc = this.nonceGen(),
        timestamp = Math.floor(d.getTime()/ 1000),
        parameters = {
            oauth_consumer_key : ck,
            oauth_timestamp : timestamp,
            oauth_nonce : nc,
            oauth_signature_method : sm
        },
        // generates a RFC 3986 encoded, BASE64 encoded HMAC-SHA1 hash
        encodedSignature = oauthSignature.generate(httpMethod, url, parameters, cs);

    this.http.get(
        url + '?oauth_consumer_key='+ck+'&oauth_timestamp='+timestamp+'&oauth_nonce='+nc+'&oauth_signature='+encodedSignature+'&oauth_signature_method='+sm
    ).subscribe(data => {
        console.log('fetched');
        console.log(data);
    });

}

public nonceGen() {
    let length = 32;
    let text = "";
    let possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    for(let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    }
    return text;
}
```

Anyone else had any luck with this?

Comment: I found a 'not working' solution here: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/6493 but that did not work for me. quote => "I replaced line https://github.com/bettiolo/oauth-signature-js/blob/master/dist/oauth-signature.js#L263 with this._key = consumerSecret;"

Comment: (looks like he was using wc api 'legacy v2' and im using 'v1' which is the latest one) ^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did finally get it working.

Somehow it wouldnt work for my local wordpress installation, but it did work for my live wordpress site:

**Angular2 code:**

```
constructor(private http: Http) {

    var oauth = OAuth({
        consumer: {
            key: 'ck_...',
            secret: 'cs_...'
        },
        signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
        hash_function: function(base_string, key) {
            return CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(base_string, key));
        }
    });

    var requestData = {
        url: 'http://siglarweb.no/wp-json/wc/v1/orders',
        method: 'GET'
    };

    this.http.get(
        requestData.url + '?' + jQuery.param(oauth.authorize(requestData))
    ).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
    });

}
```

**libraries used (installed via npm):**

npm install crypto-js --save
npm install oauth-1.0a --save

**Required files:**

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/crypto-js/crypto-js.js",
    "../node_modules/oauth-1.0a/oauth-1.0a.js"
  ]
```

Comment: how to import crypto and 0auth above the in the ts file? (sorry for the newbie question)

Comment: @GY22 - `npm install crypto-js oauth-1.0a --save` And then include core js files in index.html or load them with angular-cli config

Comment: @Steffan.can u pls say how to post data using oauth1.0a and crypto js with Angular2

Comment: @AISUNDAR That depends on the rest api server. Just use normal ajax requests and follow oauthbible.com for how u want to authorize. Jquerys ajax endpoint works fine..

Answer (score 0):

We have met issues with a `401 unauthorised` response with response code like `woocommerce_rest_invalid_signature`.

And it turns out that the URL we used when hashing is different from the URL we accessed, the URL used in the hash is *missing the trailing slash*.